# ASPxHtmlEditor resize with text inside

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, devexpress

I cant seem to find a way to resize a ASPxHtmlEditor with the text inside of it. There should be no scroll bars and all the text should always be visible. The text is loaded from the code behind. So the more text I type the bigger the control should get. Somebody please help.

*Edit:* The text is known on page load and this can be done server side if possible.

```
 <dx:ASPxHtmlEditor ID="txtMessageBody" ClientInstanceName="txtMessageBody" runat="server"
                Height="50px" Width="740px" ActiveView="Preview">
                <Toolbars>
                </Toolbars>
                <Settings AllowHtmlView="false" AllowPreview="true" AllowDesignView="false" />
                <SettingsHtmlEditing EnterMode="BR"   />
 </dx:ASPxHtmlEditor>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to find a way. Not the most elegant way but defiently gave me the results I expected and needed:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtMsg = new DataTable();

    string strConn = cConnection.GetConnectionString();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

    SqlCommand sqlCMD = new SqlCommand("GetHomeMessage", conn);

    sqlCMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    sqlCMD.Parameters.Add("@Lang", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Afrikaans";


    SqlDataAdapter sdaStat = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCMD);

    sdaStat.Fill(dtMsg);

    if (dtMsg.Rows != null && dtMsg.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        txtMessageBody.Html = dtMsg.Rows[0][0].ToString();

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        txtMessageBody.Export(DevExpress.Web.ASPxHtmlEditor.HtmlEditorExportFormat.Txt, stream);

        stream.Position = 0;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string msgBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
        msgBody = msgBody.Trim();
        stream.Close();
        reader.Close();

        Font font = new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Regular);

        Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(msgBody, font);

        txtMessageBody.Height = size.Height;

        txtMessageBody.SettingsResize.AllowResize = true;
        txtMessageBody.SettingsResize.MinWidth = 740;
    }
}
```